# Where Can I Buy / Download Solaris 11.2? It's the only version that will work for me

Tags: solaris, solaris-11

We have an Oracle 11g SE2 database with a web front end running some older code.  Basically we want to move to a better, newer dell server with SAS3/12gbs, the Dell R730.  The problem is that the web code base requires Solaris 11.2.  And the R730 needs Solaris 11.2 or 11.3. Long story, but I need to find Solaris 11.2 to make this move.

Oracle only offers downloads of Solaris 11.4.  That wont work.

Comment: 11.2 went EOL over 7 years ago. It is long past time for the developers to update to a newer version. Expecting Oracle to let you download something this old is very optimistic.

Answer (score 1):

Does the software actually check for Solaris 11.2? If not you can probably use 11.4 and things will work, unless there is something specifically checking for 11.2. People run updates over time (or should). This could be tricky however. Try Oracle Technology Network downloads (you may have to register an account to look at older versions).

If all else fails, look at the VARs (Value Added Resellers). They may be able to provide a Solaris 11.2 media-kit still, but I believe Oracle requires old versions unsold be destroyed. Definitely reach out to Dell! It's worth a shot. Otherwise you should talk to someone from Oracle and ask if they can get you 11.2 release media/download access.